# Page data disappears on page reload

Tags: javascript, decentralized-applications

I have Dapp where I load comments from the blockchain, but when i'm on the page **http://localhost:3000/coins?coin=1** and reload the page all the comments disappears so i have to go to the index page and then click on the link and then the comments is shown again. Its build in nextjs

This is my useEffect

```
    useState(() => {

        const fetchComments = async(itemId) => {
            const data = await getComments(itemId);
            setGetAllComments(data);
        }   

        fetchComments(router.query.coin);

    }, [router.query.coin]);
```

This is how i fetch my comment from the blockchain

```
   const getComments = async(itemId) => {
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
    
        const contract = signerOrProvider(signer);
        const data = await contract.getComments(itemId);
        return data;
    }
```

and this is how i map over my comments

```
<div className={`${getAllComments.length === 0 ? '' : 'h-[150px]'}}
    {getAllComments.map((comment, index) => {
        return (
         <div className='bg-nft-gray-3 font-poppins p-3 rounded-md w-full mb-3' key={index}>
            <div>
              <span className='text-sm'>
                 Author: 
                 <span> {shortenAddress(comment.author)}</span>
              </span>
              <p>{comment.text}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     )})}
</div>
```

And this is my useStateSnippet

```
const [getAllComments, setGetAllComments] = useState([]);
```

Comment: You're using `useState()` where you should be using `useEffect()`.

Comment: What a type o hahah thanks you the man